# Python: sort specific pairs of dictionaries in a list of dictionaries based on occurrence of value

Tags: python

**example:**

```
[{type:"fjsjo"}, {type:"cccc"}, {type:"xxxx"}, {type:"oooo"}]
```

results in

```
[{type:"fjsjo"}, {type:"xxxx"}, {type:"cccc"}, {type:"oooo"}]
```

I always need "xxxx" dictionary to come right before "cccc". How can I transform the dictionary so that when it detects the occurence of dictionaries containing values "cccc" and "xxxx" right next to each other or maybe there's another dictionary between those two, can be transformed so that "xxxx" is always ahead of "cccc" ?

**example:**

```
[{type:"fjsjo"}, {type:"cccc"}, {type:"oooo"} , {type:"xxxx"}, {type:"oooo"}]
```

results in

```
[{type:"fjsjo"}, {type:"xxxx"}, {type:"oooo"} , {type:"cccc"}, {type:"oooo"}]
```

Also if there's two sets or more than one of the same type, then, it should always sort the dictionaries closest to the left only.

so

**example:**

```
[{type:"cccc"}, {type:"xxxx"} , {type:"cccc"}, {type:"xxxx"}]
```

results in

```
[{type:"xxxx"}, {type:"cccc"} , {type:"xxxx"}, {type:"cccc"}]
```

whenever the occurence of "cccc" comes before "xxxx", those two dictionaries must switch places. if they have already switched places, then they cannot be switched again. So the middle two dictionaries won't switch.

**example:**

```
[{type:"cccc"}, {type:"xxxx"} , {type:"cccc"}]
```

results in

```
[{type:"xxxx"}, {type:"cccc"} , {type:"cccc"}]
```

**example:**

```
[{type:"cccc"}, {type:"oooo"} , {type:"xxxx"}, {type:"cccc"},{type:"xxxx"}]
```

results in

```
[{type:"xxxx"}, {type:"oooo"} , {type:"cccc"}, {type:"xxxx"},{type:"cccc"},{type:"cccc"}]
```

Comment: i think this not valid dictonary i think it should be 'type':'xxxx'

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар just pretend it's a valid dictionary

Comment: @user299709: it's considered polite to post code that people can copy and paste.  Otherwise for them to test their solutions they have to spend the time that you didn't.

Comment: It IS a valid dictionary, but only because type is a built-in - it will print as `<class 'type'>` in Python 3 and as `<type 'type'>` in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i considered your type to be quoted and try this

```
a=[{'type':"cccc"}, {'type':"oooo"} , {'type':"xxxx"}, {'type':"cccc"},{'type':"xxxx"}]

xxlist=[]

for index,dix in enumerate(a):
    if dix['type']=='xxxx':
        xxlist.append(a.pop(index))
new=[]
for i in a:
    if i['type']=='cccc':
        new.append(xxlist.pop(0))
        new.append(i)
    else:
        new.append(i)

if len(xxlist)>0:
    for i in xxlist:
       new.append(i)
print new
```

## output

```
[{'type': 'xxxx'}, {'type': 'cccc'}, {'type': 'oooo'}, {'type': 'xxxx'}, {'type': 'cccc'}]
```